# Wordpress - Top navigation menu issues

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress page and I have a problem with the top navigation menu. If you check my screenshot in the link, you can see a big white area under the top menu, which should not be there. It's as if the top menu extends all the way down there.

[image]

Naturally, if I remove the top navigation menu the white spice disappears, confirming this has something to do with that very menu.

I'm not well versed in wordpress. So I don't know exactly what files, code or setting I should check.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without link to the live site, it's hard to help! ;) I'm pretty sure it's a CSS issue, surely in the theme, but can we have a link?

Comment: Hello, without any code I think that is hard to find a solution. Have you write the code yourself? Have you use a plugin or a pre-made theme?

Comment: The site isn't public yet, it's on one of my servers at the moment. So you can't reach it unfortunately. Sorry about that. I am using a pre-made theme called elision, I know the name of it is unlikely to help you. But still =P

So I guess I might need to dig around in some CSS code?

Comment: Yes, you can use the developer console in your browser to check if it's a CSS problem and where is it. Can help more!

Comment: I only find a warning there for my google maps plugin, which I doubt is related. So I suppose what I need to do is to find out where the code is that is responsible for the top navigation menu, and then find out how and to what I should change it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found what was wrong. For some reason my header.php was missing line 1, which in my case should be <!DOCTYPE html>